# Proper way to integrate Tab Controller and Navigation Controller in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I looked at the other posts and some of them are older (old versions of xcode) or I really couldn't understand what I was supposed to do. So, I attempted to accomplish what I was looking to do with the information I was able to gather. I am not very good with IB or xcode, but I need to incorporate a tab controller with navigation controllers.

Basically, I am looking to have a "Primary" tab controller that links to views that are all wrapped in a navigation controller. I was able to accomplish this by adding in a new navigation controller for each "tab" (view) linked from the tab controller, but I feel like there is a better way. Or perhaps it can be done with only ONE navigation controller instead of adding a new one for each view.

I have attached a screenshot of how I accomplished it but was hoping to get some guidance on a better way to do it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Apple's HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) suggest that when you use a tab bar controller it should be the "root" of your app.

Each view controller in a tab bar controller is independent, so if a tab has a navigation controller, it's separate from whatever is in another tab. (remember that the user can switch tabs an any time, and go back to what they were doing on that tab.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I guess I was thinking that there would be  way to do   [TC] -> [NC] -> ( View, View, View)  -- the views being the different tab controlled views. If you can understand what I am trying to say there lol

Comment: No. A tab bar controller manages multiple tabs, each of which contain another view controller. A tab bar controller always has multiple independent children.